# pyqt5 enterEvent - self.sender() returns NoneType

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I have a button ***QPushButton*** - **pushButton_menu**

What I want to achieve: On button hover I need to run method ***onMenuButtonHover*** and print text of the button (need to access the button)

This is my code:

```
self.pushButton_menu.enterEvent = self.onMenuButtonHover

@pyqtSlot()
    def onMenuButtonHover(self, event):
        button = self.sender()
        print(type(button))
```

On hover method is called properly, but button is always of type **NoneType**

When I tried with clicked.connect instead of enterEvent, everything works fine - self.sender() return QPushButton object.

How I can access that QPushButton in method onMenuButtonHover?

Comment: Don't do that. Also, events are *not* signals, and `self.sender()` only works for signals. Use a subclass or event filter instead.